# Telerik radgrid filters no longer working - SP 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, telerik, radgrid

I am now managing a sharepoint site that has a series of various reports which are essentially radgrids full of data. The user has complained that filtering no longer works on most of the reports.

They all used to work fine, and for some reason now only some of the pages will filter, others do nothing. I am relatively new to telerik and cannot figure out why it would be having issues sorting.

The c# code sits on top of SP 2010

here is the code for the radgrid

```
                <%-- raok 10/2012 - add employee ID to report --%>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Employee_ID" HeaderText="Employee ID" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                    DataField="Employee_ID" Visible="true" AllowFiltering = "false">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Form_Has_Conflicts" HeaderText="Form Has Conflicts"
                    HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Form_Has_Conflicts" Visible="true" AllowFiltering = "false">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Employee_Supervisor" HeaderText="Employee Supervisor"
                    HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Employee_Supervisor" Visible="true" AllowFiltering = "false">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                            
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Last_Name" HeaderText="Last Name" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                    DataField="Last_Name" Visible="true" AllowFiltering = "false">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="DateModified" HeaderText="Date Modified"
                    HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="DateModified" Visible="true" AllowFiltering = "false">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Employee_VP" HeaderText="Employee VP" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                    DataField="Employee_VP" Visible="true" AllowFiltering = "false">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Employee_Supervisor" HeaderText="Employee Supervisor"
                    HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Employee_Supervisor" Visible="true" AllowFiltering = "false">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
        </telerik:GridTableView>
    </DetailTables>
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Title" HeaderText="Title" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
            DataField="Title" Visible="True" AllowFiltering="true" FilterControlWidth = "260px" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
            <HeaderStyle Width="290px" />
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Cycle_Year" HeaderText="Cycle Year" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                    DataField="Cycle_Year" Visible="false" AllowFiltering="false">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Form_ID" HeaderText="Form ID" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
            DataField="ID" Visible="True" AllowFiltering="false">
            <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Form_Status" HeaderText="Form Status" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
            DataField="Form_Status" Visible="false" AllowFiltering="false">
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Last_Modified_by" HeaderText="Last Modified by"
            HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Last_Modified_by" Visible="true" AllowFiltering="false">
            <HeaderStyle Width="150px" />
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Created_By" HeaderText="Created By" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
            DataField="Created_By" Visible="true" AllowFiltering="false">
            <HeaderStyle Width="150px" />
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="EmployeeFullName" HeaderText="Form Owner Last Name" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
            DataField="EmployeeFullName" Visible="false" UniqueName="EmployeeFullNameColumn" AllowFiltering="false">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>
</MasterTableView>
<ClientSettings>
    <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="True">
    </Scrolling>
    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
</ClientSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `AllowFiltering="false"` to `AllowFiltering="true"` where you need them.

For example in your code in "Title" filter works but in "Cycle_Year" it doesn't.

Also note that to use build-in filter you need to set `AllowFilteringByColumn="True"`:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="SomeID" AllowFilteringByColumn="True"
```

You can also make custom filters and much more see [***this***](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-implementing-filtering-for-gridtemplatecolumns.html) for more info and also check the contents tree out there regarding filters.

And also I have noticed that you have set `CurrentFilterFunction="SomeFilter"` this sets the starting filter option for that filter, if it cannot use that option to filter something then it will not work, for example using letter filter for the numbers.